# How to remove ' ' from a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have df column with lists. Each looks like `[1,2,3,4,'',6,7],[2,3,'',5,6]`. I want to remove the `''` in each row. I used

```
df[column].apply(lambda x: x.remove(''))
```

But it didn't work. Could some one help me? Thanks

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an list , you can use filter on it to filter out the elements that you don't want to be in the list as follows -

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,'',6,7]
my_list = list(filter(lambda x : x!='',my_list))
print(my_list)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

---

This can also be easily extended for an 2-d list using map. We will basically just apply the first function on every element of a 2-d list as follows -

```
my_list = [[1,2,3,4,'',6,7],[2,3,'',5,6]]
my_list = list(map(lambda sub_list:list(filter(lambda x : x!='',sub_list)),my_list))
print(my_list)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 3, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make an explicit filter on it: `filter(lambda x: x != "", your_list)` or use a list comprehension: `[x for x in your_list if x != ""]`. They work the same, just a matter of preference.

You don't want to filter out by a boolean method because then you'd accidentally get rid of 0s because they're "falsy" in python.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular issue, you can simply put it in a try block,
it throws an error when it comes across lists that don't have "" as an element for those you can

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
     row['column'] = list(filter(lambda x: x != "", row['column']))
```

If you just want ways to remove "" from list,

You can try,

```
new_list= [s for s in your_list if s != ""]
```

or

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != "", your_list))
```

also works

Comment: The docs clearly state to not modify dataframe when using iterrows.

Comment: But works for small datasets, Didn't know th0, thanks for the info

Comment: np, I too saw it after I had written an answer here.

Comment: Substituting `.map` or `.apply` instead would make this the best option I think.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know how exactly u got the error. if your columns just has two elemens as mentioned, it should work as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[[1,2,3,4,'',6,7],[2,3,'',5,6]]})
df['column'].apply(lambda x:x.remove(''))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
               column
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
1        [2, 3, 5, 6]
```

the problem may happened because u may have an element which have no `''` in it like `[2,3,5,6]` so in that case this error may occur. so just recreating the error we can see the same error happening.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[[1,2,3,4,'',6,7],[2,3,'',5,6],[2,3,5,6]]})
df['column'].apply(lambda x:x.remove(''))
print(df)
```

**Error Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Deva/PycharmProjects/IITJ/ML/MLf3/extras/adaf.py", line 3, in <module>
    df['column'].apply(lambda x:x.remove(''))
  File "C:\Users\Deva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2329, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:/Users/Deva/PycharmProjects/IITJ/ML/MLf3/extras/adaf.py", line 3, in <lambda>
    df['column'].apply(lambda x:x.remove(''))
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

**Solution For above situation**

To avoid that just introduce `try except`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[[1,2,3,4,'',6,7],[2,3,'',5,6],[2,3,5,6]]})
try:
    df['column'].apply(lambda x:x.remove(''))
except:
    pass
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
               column
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
1        [2, 3, 5, 6]
2        [2, 3, 5, 6]
```